# Search For String Inside Function

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible (plugin, regex, or otherwise) to search for a string inside of your current function?

given the example.

```
var text = "foo";

...

function myFunction(){
    
    ...

    var text = "local variable named the same...";

    ...

}
```

I only want to find `var text` inside the given function, and ignore anything outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visual Studio Code's search function in "Find in selection" mode (default key shortcut is `Alt-L`. [image]

Then, just select your function's body in its entirety and you're good.

Comment: well thats wonderfully simple. i guess i missed the forest for the trees. figured itd have to be some fancy plugin or something with regex.